# Repositioning element with media queries,

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a element that I want to reposition when screen size changes. I want it to change from a fixed position to centered on the page. CSS code looks like this:

```
#symboler {
    position:fixed;
    top:5px;
    right:20px;}

@media screen and (max-width: 766px) {
        #symboler {display:block; position:relative; margin:0 auto;}
}
```

Comment: so  what's not working?

Comment: The element is moving up to the left corner.

Comment: how could someone know what is wrong without seeing the rest of your `html` and `css`?

Comment: @TilwinJoy , apparently they can!

Comment: unless your page is pretty much "empty" as seen in the fiddle provided, they can't. The responsiveness and positioning of an element depends heavily on the page layout and other elements.

Comment: @Delal more your give, better we can help. TilwinJoy has a good point. Next time share more if you can. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KAz2u/) ?

**HTML**

```
<div id="symboler"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0; // reset browser value
    padding: 0; // reset browser value
}

#symboler {
    position:fixed;
    top:5px;
    right:20px;
    height: 200px; // just to display a red cube
    width: 200px; // just to display a red cube
    background: red; // just to display a red cube
}

@media screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    #symboler {
        display:block; // you can remove this if you are using a block element like div
        position:relative;
        margin:0 auto;
        right:0; // reset your value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
float:none;
width: 450px //specify width accurately in pixel or em
margin : 0 auto;
position:relative;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puLwN/2/)

#### CSS

```
#symboler {
    position:fixed;
    top:5px;
    right:20px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    #symboler {
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        margin:0 auto;
        right:0;
    }
}
```